# Is there a way to filter a ThenInclude() in an extension method

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, entity-framework-core, extension-methods

I'm trying to write a generic extension method to include a certain property (text element, themselves containing a collection of translations) that are present in many of my entity models.

Since that method would be very useful for many different kinds of entities and that I only care about retrieving the text element in only one of the Languages (the one the user prefers), I'm trying to write a generic method that could take an alpha expression as well as a LangID.

Here's What I have so far :

```cs
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<Translation>> IncludeTextBit<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TextBit>> predicate, int LangID) 
where TEntity: class
{
    var result = source.Include(predicate).ThenInclude(t => t.Translations);

    return result;
}

public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<Translation>> ThenIncludeTextBit<TEntity, TPreviousProperty>(
    this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, 
    Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TextBit>> predicate, 
    int LangID) 
where TEntity: class where TPreviousProperty : class
{
    var result = source.ThenInclude(predicate).ThenInclude(t => t.Translations);

    return result;
}
```

What I would like to achieve would be something along the line of (Although I know this direct implementation is not possible):

```cs
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<Translation>> IncludeTextBit<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TextBit>> predicate, 
    int LangID) 
where TEntity: class
{
    var result = source.Include(predicate).ThenInclude(t => t.Translations.Where(l => l.LangID==LangID));

    return result;
}
```

With an implementation that would allow me to do things like this:

```cs
var Articles = _db.Articles
    .Include(a => a.Likes)
    .IncludeTextBit(a => a.ArticleText, Lang.en)
    .Include(a => a.Tags)
    .ThenIncludeTextBit(t => t.TagName)
    .ToList();
```

I've tried many things:

**Using .Select() Instead**
I tried using the Select I think that since I'm doing a generic function I can't rely on the Select. It also looks like I can't chain them, which would be a shame. In general, I'm not sure I understand this well despite trying.

**Using EfCore plus with .IncludeFilter()**
This one seemed very promising but I lost a few hours trying to understand the limited documentation and study the few examples I found scattered around the Internet without too much success. Again It looks like this one would be pretty limiting since it can't mix with the default .Include() and .ThenInclude() of EFCore. If there ended up being a possibility tho I would gladly take the sacrifice.

**Lambda Expression Reforming**
Through all the rest I also learned to generate new lambda expressions from my predicate argument. I'll probably use that again at some point somewhere else but it seems like it won't be useful here.

**Filtering The Elements Afterward**
This ended up working, but I find it extremely ugly and less than ideal. Basically, I have a second function that loop over the translations and removes the ones not from the selected Language. I have to call it for every Text Element that an Entity may have and that adds a lot of additional code that in my opinion could be abstracted of non-necessary in some way.

At this point I spent maybe ~5 hours banging my head at the problem and I'm drained from all the mental efforts, especially that it doesn't sound like something that should be too hard to do...

I was wondering if I was missing something or maybe that after spending that much time I was too narrow-sighted to see the solution. I would be incredibly glad if someone could help me a bit or even just give me a better direction to start anew.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which syntax is preferable and do you plan to use `ThenInclude` after such Include?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I edited the post with an example of a desired resulting use. But honestly at this point if something else makes it possible I would be all for it, even if the resulting use differs a little bit

Comment: I'm almost done with this. But please post classes to test that.